# Google Docs script to fetch some web information

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to connect to a table score that exits in a flash game.
When using the browser the header that i am sending it's this one

```
POST /game/json?h=c1234567890f HTTP/1.1
Host: pt3.forgeofempires.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: sid=awsndax7nsow; req_page_info=game_v1; start_page_type=game; start_page_version=v1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://cdn.pt.forgeofempires.com/swf/Main.swf?123456789
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 161

34c4ceb6d8[{"requestClass":"ClanService","requestMethod":"getOwnClanData","requestData":[],"requestId":1,"__class__":"ServerRequest","clientVersionNumber":0.31}]
```

After looking for a while (my acknowledgement in JavaScript is not that height), i did find some examples and after understanding them i did make my own code.

```
function test(){
  var header =
      {
        'Host': 'pt3.forgeofempires.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Cookie': 'sid=awsndax7nsow; req_page_info=game_v1; start_page_type=game; start_page_version=v1',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'http://cdn.pt.forgeofempires.com/swf/Main.swf?123456789',
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-length': '161',
        '': '96c4ceb6d9[{"requestClass":"ClanService","requestMethod":"getOwnClanData","requestData":[],"requestId":4,"__class__":"ServerRequest","clientVersionNumber":0.31}]'
      }

  var url = "http://pt3.forgeofempires.com/game/json?h=c1234567890f";
  var h = {
    'method'  : "post",
    'payload' : header
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, h);
  return response;
}
```

When i run the code it goes always to the login page.
Not sure if this is happening because of any script error or simple because it's a different ip address accessing to my account.
No sure as well how to send the last part, because the last part it's a text data only.

Any help will be appreciated... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding your headers as a payload. UrlFetchApp provides a way to add headers. Use that

```
var h = {
    'method'  : "post",
    'headers' : header
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, h);
```

I'm not sure what your payload is. In the list of headers, there is a blank header - is this the payload ? If yes, then you have to add the payload separately.

```
var h = {
    'method'  : "post",
    'headers' : header,
    'payload' : '96c4ceb6d9[{"requestClass":"ClanService","requestMethod":"getOwnClanData","requestData":[],"requestId":4,"__class__":"ServerRequest","clientVersionNumber":0.31}]'
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, h);
```

Note: Ensure that you remove the blank header from the list of headers.

Comment: Thanks mate, guess i miss understood the payload thing when reading about it. It's working now...